# Javascript onclick event on HTML element

Tags: javascript, html, click

I have got the code which allows me to search through a list of products and then generate an HTML list of those matching the search term. My next step is to be able to click either on the accompanying picture of the product or its name and then add this into the shopping cart section. I understand an onclick event would assist in doing this but am not sure of the implementation. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Addition: I tried the code

HTML

```
<img class="imgInteract">
```

JS

```
var imgInteract = document.getElementsByClassName('img')
```

to try and be able to select the img elements that are generated in the list but it didn't seem to work.

HTML

```
<form>
  <p>Please insert the items</p>
  <input type="text" id="box" />
</form>

<div id="root"></div>

<h3>
shopping cart
</h3>
```

CSS

```
  img {
    height: 100px;
  }
  li {
    display: inline-block;
  }
```

JS

```
const catalog = {

  GalaxyTablet: {
    name: "GalaxyTablet",
    key: "galaxytablet",
    keywords: ["galaxy", "tablet", "samsung"],
    price: 800,
    image: "https://www.jbhifi.co.nz/FileLibrary/ProductResources/Images/150044-M-HI.jpg"
  },
  GalaxyPhone: {
    name: "GalaxyPhone",
    key: "galaxyphone",
    keywords: ["galaxy", "phone", "samsung"],
    price: 1000,
    image: "https://assets.kogan.com/files/product/etail/Samsung-/S10WHT_03.jpg?auto=webp&canvas=753%2C502&fit=bounds&height=502&quality=75&width=753"
  },
  HTCPhone: {
    name: "HTCPhone",
    key: "htcphone",
    keywords: ["htc", "phone"],
    price: 650,
    image: "https://cdn.mos.cms.futurecdn.net/ca063713e185be46e62ec2eb3762a540.jpg"
},

};

const form = document.querySelector("form");

form.addEventListener("submit", submitHandler);

function submitHandler(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  const searchTerm = form.box.value;
  const results = search(searchTerm);

  render(results);
}

function search(searchTerm) {
  return Object.keys(catalog)
    .filter((key) => catalog[key].keywords.includes(searchTerm.toLowerCase()))
    .map((key) => catalog[key]);
}

function render(results) {
  const root = document.querySelector("#root");
  const list = results.map(itemToLi).join("");

  root.innerHTML = `<ul>
    ${list}
  </ul>`;
}

function itemToLi(item) {
  return `<li>${item.name}</li>$ ${item.price}<li> <li><img src="${item.image}"></li>`;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should change your render method for the product list so both the image and product name are under the same `<li>` tag.

So your item to li looks like:

```
function itemToLi(item) {
  return `<li data-productkey="${item.key}">${item.name}$ ${
    item.price
  }<img src="${item.image}"></li>`;
}
```

Then in your render function. You add a event listener to the li instead, so it will track the event when you click either on the image or on the product name.

```
function render(results) {
  const root = document.querySelector("#root");
  const list = results.map(itemToLi).join("");

  root.innerHTML = `<ul>
    ${list}
  </ul>`;

  const products = document.querySelectorAll("li");
  products.forEach(product => {
    product.addEventListener("click", e => {
      console.log("added ", product.dataset.productkey);
    });
  });
}
```

You can use the [data attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) to store the key of your product. So you know exactly which one was clicked.

You can see the [**Working demo here**.](https://codesandbox.io/s/nameless-currying-lyuqw?file=/src/index.js)

Answer (score 0):

What you'd like to do here is this:

```
function render(results) {
 ...

  root.innerHTML = `<ul>
     ${list}
  </ul>`;

  attachOnclickHandlerToEachImage();
}

function attachOnclickHandlerToEachImage(){
  var imgInteract = document.getElementsByTagName('img')

  for (let img of imgInteract) {
    img.addEventListener('click', addToCart.bind(this));
  }

}

function addToCart(img){
   console.log(img + "added to cart");
}
```

Comment: This would only set the events for the current elements by the className img, OP is appending new ones based on search, those appended will not have the event handler.

Comment: OP has not said this. But in any case, this will be the way to move forward.

Comment: Op has not said this? It's in the literal code, root.innerHTML = ..., plus "and then generate an HTML list of those matching"

Comment: If you look at the code close enough, you'd understand they are creating a list of images and appending at the `root`. What they need there is to `bind` each of the images with a handler.

Comment: exactly they are creating a list of images and appending at root, and yea they need to bind each image with an on click handler, your code does not do that, it binds the first collection of classes by the name "imgs" and then sets THOSE  current elements' handlers, new elements appended will not have those handlers. It's not an event listener waiting for current & new elements, it's static code for the current elements that pass that selector.

Comment: Ok let me change it to `getElementsByTagName`. Is that okay?

Answer (score -1):

Add a class to your images and then use the event to add them to shoppin cart

```
function itemToLi(item) {
  return `<li>${item.name}</li>$ ${item.price}<li> <li><img  class="imgInteract" src="${item.image}"></li>`;
}

root.addEventListener('click',(e)=>{
    if(e.target.className=='imgInteract')
 console.log('add to shopping cart',e.target.src)
})
```

or you can add the class to the `li` and then retrieve the item you want to add

```
function itemToLi(item) {
  return `<li class="select">${item.name}</li>$ ${item.price}<li> <li><img  class="imgInteract" src="${item.image}"></li>`;
}

root.addEventListener('click',(e)=>{
    if(e.target.className=='select')

     console.log('add to shopping cart',e.target.textContent)
})
```